# How do you safely set up a offline deterministic wallet?

Tags: wallet, electrum, deterministic-wallets

There is a good tutorial for setting up a safe offline wallet with a regular bitcoin wallet [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/How_to_set_up_a_secure_offline_savings_wallet).

If I want to set up a safe deterministic offline wallet (i.e. [Electrum](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Electrum)). What would be the right steps?

Should I just store the seed, or also backup the private keys?

Comment: You can do all that and more with [Armory](https://bitcoinarmory.com/using-offline-wallets-in-armory/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a deterministic wallet the only thing you need to keep safe is your seed / passphrase to be able to restore it in the future

Here you can find a tutorial on how to make transactions with an offline Electrum wallet using your Master Public Key

http://electrum.org/tutorials.html#offline-mpk